# Run SQLite commands on database in one app from another

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I have an SQLite database stored in the `assets` resources of one application used to load UI and other stuff into the app, mainly just holding text nothing out of the ordinary. I want to be able to get a writable version of this database so I can modify it from another application.

**Example:**

First application is on the market with limited number of enabled features. User gets to a certain point where they need to buy extra content to do more stuff in the app. The original app has these features but they are not enabled in the app using the database. I want the user then to download a second app from the market which is just used to change one field in the database from disabled to enabled thus unlocking the new features.

I have an idea I may need to use content providers but my understanding is once created they are accessible to all applications. I need it, for piracy reasons I guess, to only be able to communicate with apps signed off by my key.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sam,

I understand what you intend to do, but you are going about it the wrong way.  Your 'Unlock App' would not be able to modify the Database in the assets folder of your 'Free App'.  That's just general android security model stuff.

You may want to look at this question: [How can I use the paid version of my app as a "key" to the free version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062946/how-can-i-use-the-paid-version-of-my-app-as-a-key-to-the-free-version)

It describes how you can create a 'Unlock App' on the market to unlock features of your 'Free app' without needing to actually modify any of the original data in the 'Free App'.

Good luck