# External app to act as a full version key

Tags: android

I have noticed some apps use a second app just to act as their key for full version - this way there is no need to have two versions of the app just the free one and a full version unlocker.

How would I go about implementing this?

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need is here [How can I use the paid version of my app as a "key" to the free version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062946/how-can-i-use-the-paid-version-of-my-app-as-a-key-to-the-free-version/)

Answer (score 0):

In Android intents are self contained, so the free app could have say 3 intents. And when the user runs the free app, he interacts with the 3 intents. The paid app has say 3 intents and also call the 3 intents of the free app, thus providing the paid + free functionality in the app. I haven't implemented this but I think this would be the way to do this. Others can correct me if I am wrong.

I personally would just overwrite the free app with the paid app and keep this simpler to manage. In terms of maintenance this is one less app to track and manage features.

Comment: This is not how I see it done on other apps - they have the full version enabler just installed - then you still use the free version but it has features unlocked - this is a one time thing to implement should not require much maintenance

Comment: Hm, do the two apps have different package names? One other way is to use server to unlock features, after the user buys the paid app, on first launch of paid app it sends some user info to server, thus allowing it to control what features are blocked and unlocked.

Comment: Yes the apps have different package name. The answers you proposed are legitimate means of the ultimate goal but not the one I am looking for (nor are they good ways IMHO). Thanks for the answer though