# Creating a Pro Key

Tags: android, key

I want to make a Pro Key app for my application. I have read very interesting answers in this web ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062946/how-can-i-use-the-paid-version-of-my-app-as-a-key-to-the-free-version)). I will upload that apk to PlayStore so people will need to buy it in order to have the main App change from Lite to Pro, unblocking all the hidden features and removing ads.

Now I have a question:
There are a lot of "Apk extractors" available in the market. So one user could pay for the Key, then use the "apk extractor" and distribute the "ProKey.apk" in the web. This way people could just download the ProKey.apk file and run it.

Is there any solution for this?

Can the main App check that the ProKey has been installed from PlayStore instead of a direct apk file?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The PackageManager class supplies the [getInstallerPackageName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstallerPackageName%28java.lang.String%29)
>   method that will tell you the package name of whatever installed the
>   package you specify. Side-loaded apps will not contain a value.

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10809481/1932105

**google**'s package name: `com.android.vending`