# Combining both free and paid versions for android

Tags: android

I want to release the app in both **free and paid versions**. But I have a problem here. As per my knowledge, the app will be updated when the version number is increased in the manifest having the user saved data uncleared. I want the same feature when the user opts from free to paid application i.e., If user downloads the free app and saves his data(I am using `sqlite for persistence`) and uses it for few days. `If the user likes it and go for paid app for more features, I want the user saved data as it is`. Just like as he updates the app.

If I just change the version number for free and paid apps, what if I want to update the free one to resolve some bugs when it is gone live. So, can someone suggest achieving this? I am very confused on how to go further. Thanks.

p.s: I have seen some post maintaining the common things as library project, but it doesn't seem it is fit. Because I have to change the package names for those. If I change the package names, the lite cannot be updated as the paid one automatically.

Answer (score 3):

I think your best two solutions are:

1. In-app billing where the user can buy the paid features of your app
2. Have another app which works as a key to your main app. So when the user buys the key app, you can have your main app check if key app is installed and unlock the paid features

Some links with more info:

- [How can I use the paid version of my app as a "key" to the free version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062946/how-can-i-use-the-paid-version-of-my-app-as-a-key-to-the-free-version)
- [Creating a Pro Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465315/creating-a-pro-key/19465329)
- [Trial/Free & Full Version VS. Free App + In-app billing?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/121081/trial-free-full-version-vs-free-app-in-app-billing)

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention. I don't want to go for in-app billing.

Comment: Then if you are looking for a simple solution, I think your only option is having some kind of key app for your main app to check against. You could have two separate apps (one paid, another free) but then you would need to store the user data on a server or use a shared content provider to ensure they are in sync across the apps.

Comment: +1 for the answer. If user installs key app, then he would have two apps one is main and another is key app which would make two apps for one work.

Comment: Yes. But the key app would take you very little work to build. From the user point of view, you can have it just have a button to launch your main app or hide it entirely from the list of installed apps by removing the `<intent-filter>` for the launcher activity in the key app manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `android:sharedUserId` [manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html) element.

> android:sharedUserId
>
> The name of a Linux user ID that will be shared with other
>   applications. By default, Android assigns each application its own
>   unique user ID. However, if this attribute is set to the same value
>   for two or more applications, they will all share the same ID —
>   provided that they are also signed by the same certificate.
>   Application with the same user ID can access each other's data and, if
>   desired, run in the same process.

If you can get that to work, it means you could for example allow the paid version to "import" data from the free version.