# Android App Billing per Account

Tags: android, in-app-billing

How to set app billing to buy app just once per account ?? 
Can't find any examples with such situation. If possible provide some external links to see.

Comment: Sounds like something that should already be handled by the Play store.  If I'm understanding correctly, you want your app (the entire package) to be purchased up to once per account.

Comment: Exactly . The only examples i found were with donations only.

Comment: So what is your question? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I want an example or tutorial with such situation . I made an app . This app has an upgrade button . After i click and buy it , to bind app by google account

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'upgrade' you mean within the app, meaning the user has already downloaded the app for free.

This could be accomplished by in app purchases (tied to Google account if you're using the Google Play API) or by purchasing a separate app (i.e. PRO version) which interfaces with the current app.

Here's the docs for in app purchases:

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html

And here's another SO question if you want to go the PRO/unlocker route:

[How can I use the paid version of my app as a "key" to the free version?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3062946/1059070)